# Isomorphism between (even, odd) and (positive, negative)

Tags: category-theory

This is a problem in [Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052171916X)

> Find an isomorphism
> $$
> (\{{\rm odd}, {\rm even}\}, +) \stackrel{f}{\to} (\{{\rm positive}, {\rm negative} \}, \times)
> $$
> HINT: There are only two invertible maps of sets from $\{{\rm odd}, {\rm even}\}$ to $\{{\rm positive}, {\rm negative} \}$. One of them 'respects the combining rules', but the other doesn't

I've a little stumped with this question. This is one of the maps I've come up with

$$
f(x): \begin{cases}
-k & {\rm if} & x = 2k - 1, ~~k=1,2, ...\\
k & {\rm if} & x = 2k, ~~ k = 0, 1, 2,
\end{cases}
$$

This will map odd to positive numbers, and even to negative numbers, and is invertible. The issue is that it does not preserve the combining rules, e.g. if $x = 2m - 1$ is odd, and $y = 2n$ even

$$
f(x + y) = f(2(m + n) - 1) = -(m + n) \tag{1}
$$

but on the other hand

$$
f(x) \times f(y) = f(2m + 1) \times f(2n) = (-m) \times (n) = -mn \tag{2}
$$

Clearly

$$
f(x + y) \not= f(x)\times f(y)
$$

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Don't think about the underlying numbers here. Just work with the labels 'odd' and 'even' (with the addition rule you know they have to have) and the labels 'positive' and 'negative' (and the multiplication rule they have to have).

Comment: Just to rephrase what Chessanator said, you seem to be trying to construct a map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ sending odd numbers to positive numbers and even numbers to negative numbers while sending addition to multiplication. This is, indeed, impossible, but this is not what you're asked to do. You have two *two-element sets* here; ignoring for the moment the $+$ and $\times$, you might as well be talking about invertible maps between $\{a,b\}$ and $\{\leftarrow,\rightarrow\}$. The elements of these sets are literally the *words* odd,even,positive,negative, not any numbers at all.

Comment: @Chessanator I'm such an idiot, thanks so much for the answer. It makes total sense, if you want to expand on your comment and put it as an answer I will be happy to accept it. Thanks

Comment: @KevinArlin I was totally going the wrong way about this, thank you very much for your comment, helped me figured this out.

Answer (score 1):

Let g be the map of sets from {odd,even} to {pos, neg} that sends odd to pos and even to neg.

g is an isomorphism for obvious reason (existence of an inverse)

Now, suppose you want to "add structure" to g and make it an isomorphism between $(\{{\rm odd}, {\rm even}\}, +)$ and $(\{{\rm pos}, {\rm neg} \}, \times)
$. Let's prove that the following equation doesn't not hold:

$g(odd + even) \stackrel{?}{=}  g(odd) * g(even)$

$g(odd + even)    = g(odd)$  (odd + even = odd, combining rule for elements in {odd,even})

```
             = pos             g(odd) = pos by construction of g
```

g(odd) * g(even) = pos * neg       by construction of g

```
             = neg             (pos * neg = neg, combining rule in ({pos, neg}, *))
```

g(odd+even) is *different* from g(odd) * g(even) that's why the combining rule is not followed by g.